# Code won't run an elif statement in a function

Tags: python, function, audio

I am making a simple calculator still in its developing stages.  I also wanted to make an audio version.  Of course, the audio version is a lot more complex and that is where I'm having most of my problems.  This specific one will run the audio file I want to play if the answer is 1 digit, but not 2.  So it won't run the elif statement inside the answer_audio() function.  It won't run the entire elif statement as I have tried to use a print function just inside it and that won't work either

here is my function for playing the audio file for the answer

```
def answer_audio():
    ans_split = str(answer).split()
    amount = len(ans_split)
    if amount == 1:
        for x in range(10):
            if x == int(ans_split[0]):
                ps(f"Units/{x}.m4a")
    elif amount == 2:
        print("gaming")
        for x in range(10):
            if x == int(ans_split[0]):
                if int(ans_split[0]) == 1:
                    for i in range(10):
                        if i == int(ans_split[1]):
                            ps(f"Teens/1{i}.m4a")
                else:
                    ps(f"Tens/{x}.m4a")
                    if ans_split[1] != 0:
                        ps(f"Units/{ans_split[1]}.m4a")
```

and here is the actual calculator bit (you need to put spaces in between characters and it will only work for 2 numbers, no matter what digit though)

```
equation = input("Equation: ")

cal = equation.split()

if cal[1] == "x" or cal[1] == "X":
    answer = (int(cal[0]) * int(cal[2]))
    print(answer)
    answer_audio()

elif cal[1] == "-":
    answer = (int(cal[0]) - int(cal[2]))
    print(answer)

elif cal[1] == "+":
    answer = (int(cal[0]) + int(cal[2]))
    print(answer)

elif cal[1] == "/":
    answer = (int(cal[0]) / int(cal[2]))
    print(answer)
```

Comment: What's the sample input for which you're facing the problem? Which elif statement is not executing?

Comment: Please give more info so more people could help you.

Comment: Try to come up with a more minimal exampe - for instance, when you have trouble figuring out how if / elif works, all the audio calculator context is not important. Try to compile a small example - maybe you find out the error lies in some other place you did not think about ...

Answer (score 0):

If `answer` is an integer, then `str(answer).split()` is simply going to be the same as `[str(answer)]`, because [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) without any arguments will split on whitespace.

If you want to count digits, you can just use `len(str(answer))`, or if you want a list of digits for some other operation later, you can pass the `str` (which is already an iterable) to `list()` like this: `ans_split = list(str(answer))`.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, you could consider marking it as accepted by clicking the checkmark icon on the left.